# Visualizing level set of multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields, stokes-theorem

Consider the vector field $\mathbf{F} : \Bbb{R}^3 \to \Bbb{R}^3, \mathbf{F}(x, y, z) = (2y, -z^2, 3x).$

a) Compute the flux of $\mathbf{F}$ through the surface $S$ given by $S = \{{(x, y, z) : x^2 + y^2 + z^3 + z = 1, z \ge 0}\}$ and oriented upwards.

b) Compute the flux of $\nabla \times \mathbf{F}$ through $S$ (defined in part a)).

To answer these, I would use Gauss's Theorem and Stokes' Theorem for parts a) and b), respectively. However, for both of these, I need to determine what the boundary of $S$ is, which I don't know how to do without assistance of graphing software. How could I visualize $S,$ as well as surfaces like $S$ which aren't standard quadric surfaces (spheres, hyperboloids, paraboloids, ellipsoids, etc.) in order to be able to solve problems like these?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(w)=w+w^3$. This is an increasing function on $\mathbb{R}$, so it has an inverse, and you can obtain the graph $y=f^{-1}(x)$ by reflection of the graph $y=f(x)$ across the line $y=x$.
(Note that $f(w) > w$ for $w>0$, so $0 < f^{-1}(w) < w$ for $w>0$.)

This means that you can solve the equation $x^2+y^2+z+z^3=1$ for $z$:
$$
z = f^{-1}(1-x^2-y^2)
,
$$
where $z$ is nonnegative iff $1-x^2-y^2$ is.

Now introduce a radial variable $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and draw the curve $z=f^{-1}(1-r^2)$ in the $rz$-plane for $0 \le r \le 1$. (Start with the curve $z=1-r^2$ and move each point $(r,z)$ on that curve, for $0\le r < 1$, a bit downwards, since $0 < f^{-1}(w) < w$ for $w>0$; [see plot on Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+z%5E3%2Bz%3D1-r%5E2%2C+r%3D0..1)).

Then rotate this curve around the $z$ axis to obtain the surface $S$.